# Immutable update function is not working

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I am using immutable.js function update() and updateIn(). But the result is not getting as expected.

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({cartList: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Product One",
            quantity:1
        },{
            id: 2,
            name: "Product Two",
            quantity:2
        }],
    productList:[{
            name: "Product One",
            id: 1,
            availability:2
        },{
            name: "Product Two",
            id: 2,
            availability:2
        },{
            name: "Product Three",
            id: 3,
            availability:4
        }]});
var action = {
            id: 2,
            name: "Product Two",
            quantity:2
        };

 initialState = initialState.updateIn(['cartList'], cartList => cartList.push(action)).toJS();
 initialState = initialState.updateIn(['productList'], productList => {
            productList.map(product => {
                    if(action.id ==  product.get("id")){
                        return product.update("availability", value => value-1);
                } else
                        return product
            });
}).toJS();

console.log(initialState.toJS());
```

I tried it in jsfiddle. But there is no change in initialState.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `initialState` `const`, which means that you cannot change the value held by that variable (it's a variable, despite the fact it can't be changed). So

```
initialState = initialState.updateIn(/*...*/);
```

won't update the value in `initialState`.

If you want it to, change `const` to `var` or `let`.

Regarding `productList`: Note that `Array#map` **returns** the new array, it doesn't modify the existing array. So you may have wanted:

```
productList = productList.map(/*...*/);
```

---

You probably know this, but I'll just flag it up anyway: `const` is a new feature of JavaScript as of ES2015 (ES6). It's supported in up-to-date engines like V8 (in Chrome and NodeJS), but a large number of browsers don't have it yet (either because they just don't have it yet, or because people are using older versions that were released before the spec was finalized.) If you didn't *mean* to be using ES2015 features, you'll want `var` rather than `let` (as `let` is also new).

Comment: Even if you change `initialState` to var or let, productList will be undefined after the map function. Can you help me with that??

Comment: @AmalaJames: It would help if the code were indented/formatted in a reasonable, consistent way. You can use anything you want in your own code, but when asking for help, it's useful to make the code readable to others.

Comment: @AmalaJames: I've updated the answer, though. You're not using the return value of `map`.

Comment: Crowder: Thank You. i missed the return type.